# Best way to read a textbox line by line in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, textbox, input

What's the best way to read in a the contents of a textbox line by line in VB.net 2.0?

I'm currently using the one listed at [TextBoxBase.Lines Property at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines(VS.85).aspx) but wanted to know what other ways could one read in a textbox line by line in VB.net.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Lines property is what you want to use.  Parsing the Text property yourself requires more code and doesn't make it faster.  Write a better question if you have a reason to look for an alternative.

Comment: Was just checking to see if there was a better alternative...it seems not though...thanks.

Answer (score 11):

It might not be the best way, but you could always use TextBox.Text.Split(vbNewLine), which will return an array of string. You could use that in a for each loop

```
For Each strLine As String In TextBox.Text.Split(vbNewLine)
...
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked like a charm!

```
For Each s As String In Me.TextBox1.Lines  
     Dim line As String = s
    ...
Next
```